# Custom properties with entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have 3 entites, Test, sections and questions.
a test holds many sections, and a section holds many questions.

how do I add a questions property to my Test entity, the property would contain all the questions in all the sections of that test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will add non mapped property:

```
public IEnumerable<Question> Questions
{
    get 
    {
        return Sections.SelectMany(s => s.Questions);
    }
}
```